# adding keyup and keydown eventlisteners to div

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have a threejs scene that implements some hotkeys using 'keyup' and 'keydown' eventlisteners like so

```
//works
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => this.onKeyDown(e), false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.onKeyUp(e), false);
window.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => this.onPointerUp(e), false);
window.addEventListener('pointermove', (e) => this.onPointerMove(e), false);
window.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => this.onPointerDown(e), false);
```

the above code works fine. The problem arises when I move the scene into a div and change the code to the following

```
//working
this.container.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => this.onPointerUp(e), false);
this.container.addEventListener('pointermove', (e) => this.onPointerMove(e), false);
this.container.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => this.onPointerDown(e), false);
//not working
this.container.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => this.onKeyDown(e), false);
this.container.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.onKeyUp(e), false);
```

for some reasons the keydown and keyup event listeners stop working but the pointer eventlisteners all work fine.

the container looks sth like this

```
this.container = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:
like Behrouz mentioned in the comment, setting tabindex for the 'canvasWrapper' div fixes the issue
i.e.

```
<div id = "canvasWrapper" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: have you tried setting `tabindex` on the canvas element? like `<canvas tabindex='1'></canvas>`

Comment: The element will only fire if the user is focused on the canvas wrapper (or on its children if the event bubbles).

Comment: setting tabindex for the wrapper div fixes the issue thanx

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, `this` points to a given instance of an object. Simple.

On the other hand, the JavaScript `this` pointer is a subject which requires a lot of reading and trial and error to understand.

The problem arises from the way the key functions are called.

The event will be triggered by the `window` object.

In JavaScript, the calling object, `window` in this case, becomes the `this` pointer.

You need to bind the function call to ensure the `this` pointer points to the intended object.

Here’s an example:

```
var x = {
    message: 'hello',
    init: function () {
        this.addEventListener('keyUp', sayMessage)
    },
    sayMessage: function () {
       console.log(this.message);
    }
}

x.init();

// called directly prints hello
x.sayMessage()

// called from the event lister
// Error: window.message is undefined
```

Bind the pointer to your object:

```
x.sayMessage.bind(x)
```